# What's the standard smooth structure on manifold of smooth functions

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$ be the space of all smooth functions on $M$. My question is

(a) What is the standard smooth structure that makes $C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$ a smooth manifold? That is, how can we define coordinate charts on $C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$?

(b) Let $f\in C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$, what is the tangent space $T_{f}\left(C^{\infty}\left(M\right)\right)$?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a vector space. If you believe in manifolds modeled on particularly general topological vector spaces, like Frechet spaces, then the identity map is a perfectly good chart. If you believe only in finite dimensional manifolds, you're out of luck.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Can you mention more clearly about my question? I suppose $M$ has a finite dimension.

Comment: $C^\infty(M)$ is not even locally compact. It is not a finite dimensional manifold. Did you want it to be?

Comment: I know that $C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$ is not a finite dimensional manifold, but my question is "is it a smooth manifold in some sense?" I just know about finite dimensional manifold.